# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectPage' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, lodash, material-ui

I am using React, Material-UI and lodash but the following code within the     render method gives me an error saying 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectPage' of undefined" :

```
        tmppage = _.map(_.range(0, this.state.groupsdt.length), function (i) {

                    return (
                            <MenuItem >
                                <IconButton onClick={() => { {this.selectPage(i)} }}><WebAsset /></IconButton>
                                Page {i + 1}
                            </MenuItem>
                        )
        });
```

I've defined this.selectPage in constructor(props) as follows :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                    loading: true,
                    modalopen: false,
                    menuopen: false,
                    urls:null,
                    groupsdt:null,
                    webkey:null,

                    currentpage:0,

                    currentBreakpoint: 'lg',
                    mounted: false,
                    layouts: {lg: null},

                    opentopublic:false,

                  };

    this.addPage      = this.addPage.bind(this);
    this.selectPage   = this.selectPage.bind(this);
    this.addBox       = this.addBox.bind(this);
    this.removeBox    = this.removeBox.bind(this);
    this.doPost       = this.doPost.bind(this);

    this.doHome       = this.doHome.bind(this);
}
```

Please tell me what I'm missing... and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be coming from using `function` keyword in callback for `map`, try using arrow function instead. You can read more on arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

```
_.map(_.range(0, this.state.groupsdt.length), (i)=> {
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved it!
Some of my code with "function" keyword work, but it doesn't use "this". 
Can you tell me the difference between having a "function" keyword in callback and not having a "function" keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is very right - You should change the callback inside your map to an arrow function that would make this **callback bound to its lexical scope** which is your class and this will have the **selectPage** property

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This also helped!

Comment: To explain the difference between an arrow function and function I recommend reading this article https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/es5-functions-vs-es6-fat-arrow-functions-864033baa1a